# Code Music Streaming in Background with Android App

Tags: android

I have built a website that streams mp3 playlists using javascript and created an android app that uses WebView to embed the site. Unfortunately the music stops when the phone sleeps. Is it possible to code the app to maintain the javascript executing to keep music playing while running in background? I would like it to function similar to Pandora as an example but not sure if this is possible using WebView.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i test this code so keep music playing while running in background, maybe help you:

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // Enable javascript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            return customUriHanlder(uri);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return customUriHanlder(uri);
        }

        private boolean customUriHanlder(final Uri uri) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Uri =" + uri);
            final String host = uri.getHost();
            final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            // you can set your specific condition
            if (true) {
                // Returning false means that you are going to load this url in the webView itself
                return false;
            } else {
                // Returning true means that you need to handle what to do with the url
                // open web page in a Browser
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the webpage
    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webView.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That functioned the same as what I had. I probably should have been more clear - the music will play when the phone sleeps but when a song endsand the JavaScript would on desktop play the next track things just stop. If I push the power button a song will play. I'm pretty sure adding a step counter to keep the app going wouldn't work due to some security issues they are concerned about.